# How to execute a .exe file using PsExec in Finalbuilder

Tags: automation, exe, build-automation, psexec, finalbuilder

I need to be able to run a .exe file on a remote VM using Finalbuilder. I'm currently using PsExec, which I can get to run .msi files, but not .exe files. On a .exe file, here's what I'm trying:

Under Program file I have

```
msiexec
```

These are my parameters

```
/i C:\[filepath].exe INSTALLDIR=C:\[path] INSTALLMETHOD=silent 
INSTALLALIAS=LIVE INSTALLREBOOTMETHOD=0 /qn /l*v C:\[log path].txt
```

Can PsExec not run .exe files, or is there an alternative to PsExec that works better?